# Shared Transition fragment to fragment not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, transition, shared

I have an activity with view pager having three fragments. I started another top fragment having view pager with fragments inside. Everything is fine and I am successful to do all this. But when I use addSharedElement for shared transition from fragment to fragment, there is no animation happening at all. I replace fragment with new top fragment like below:

```
   View transitionView = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_image_view);
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .addSharedElement(transitionView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(transitionView))
                .commit();
```

and in my next fragment onCreate I did:

```
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().supportPostponeEnterTransition();
    }
   }
```

then in  onCreateView I implement another viewpager with fragment. After implementing view pager, The fragment I want to show I did:

```
     desiredFragmentToShow.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(

     getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans));

     desiredFragmentToShow.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(

     getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
```

and in desiredFragmentToShow in onViewCreated I did:

```
    activity.supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
```

but there is no animation at all. Please help if any body have an idea.

Comment: So if you are using shared elements between Fragments, why are you getting the Activity involved with it? For example you're call `getActivity().supportPostponeEnterTransition();` should be `postponeEnterTransition();` etc..

Comment: @Mark Keen I did  'postponeEnterTransition();' in 'onCreate()' of next container fragment of view pager and 'startPostponedEnterTransition();' in fragment inside view pager, still imageview in view pager fragment is not animating at all.

Comment: @WakilAhmad have you succeed with solving the issue?

Comment: @Jocky Doe not yet

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer is in kotlin but I believe it's no big deal

I've found that calling `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in `onViewCreated` is too late.

ViewPager Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val transition = TransitionInflater
        .from(context)
        .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = transition
    /* The return transition probably should be set here as well on the way back
       but I havent't try that yet so I nullify it... */
    sharedElementReturnTransition = null
    postponeEnterTransition()
    // ... your code
}
```

Page Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    startPostponedEnterTransition()
}
```

and that works...

Unfortunately if you want to put a listener on the transition it works only if you define it in the `ViewPager` because in the `Page Fragment` if you set listener on the casted shared transition it doesn't trigger.

```
val transition = parentFragment!!.sharedElementEnterTransition
```

Comment: I see. If you're posponning it in the `Page Fragment`  instead of the `ViewPager Fragment` that might be the reason. Anyway if you follow the steps I've shared I'm sure you'll get the transition, good luck